# How can I make a durable connection between a PCB and outside of case?

Tags: pcb

How would one go about connecting an LED or a sensor to a printed circuit board? You could use a male header pin and a dupont cable, but that seems like it would easily be able to slip out. Is there any standard solution to this problem? Soldering is out of the question because anyone should be able to connect the wire without having to have any special skill.

Comment: FWIW, the answer is: "_Use connectors. Thumb through the connectors section in your favorite fat catalog.  See what you like_".  At the same time, your question is not clear (at least for me).  You didn't write what your box is doing, what environment it will operate in, what are the signals that you want to connect.  No schematic or block diagram for the system.

Comment: Field-installable equipment usually uses screw terminals, in which the wire is clamped in a mechanism that is opened/closed with a screwdriver.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could buy an LED like [this](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/SSI-LXH600GD-150/67-1189-ND/145091) with wires attached, and attach a lockable connector to the wires for the end user to connect.

Or you could use a board mounted LED and then use a [light pipe](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/optoelectronics/optics-leds-light-pipes/524541?k=light%20pipes) to get the light out of the case.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the device is subjected to excessive amounts of shock, dupont cable on a 5.88mm male header pin is very reliable. If even higher reliability is required, adding more connections than strictly required will increase the extraction force proportionally. Note that the cable should be secured against either the board or the chassis in order to prevent any slack from swinging around regardless.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of existing solutions. A [latching connector](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/1735447-3/A100020-ND/2077925) for instance.

If you're trying to keep it really cheap you can just add two mounting holes near the cable attachment, this way you can zip-tie the cable to the board.